# Good place to start learning ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a two years of experience of programming in Visual C# and Visual C++. I would like to know some good online sources to start learning ASP.NET or anything else I should/need to learn before diving into ASP.NET. I found some online videos that are proving to be quite useful. Perhaps I would like to know about some open source projects where I can have a look at the ASP.NET code directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, but I'm going to have to suggest the immediately obvious first:

[Official Microsoft ASP .Net Site](http://www.asp.net)

There's a link at the top to both "Get Started" and "Learn", and I have found this site incredibly useful over the past year or so.

Answer (score 4):

Speaking as a convert from WinForms to the Web, I offer the following tips

- Learn the ASP.NET Life-cycle
- Get to grips with the concepts of client vs server-side code; know how pages are served up etc
- Don't bite off too much too soon, there are A LOT of new things to learn, and it changes very quickly.  But you don't need to be writing a full-blown AJAX web app straight away.

Answer (score 2):

I like http://www.asp.net/learn/ it has some great tuts and some cool videos that walk you through the processes.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, CodeProject (www.codeproject.com) has lots of excellent articles related to ASP.NET.
Regarding projects, there are plenty of ASP.NET applications in CodePlex (www.codeplex.com) or SourceForge.
Regarding a specific ASP.NET application, http://www.cuyahoga-project.org/ its a great application to see.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/

Loads of ASP.NET articles/tutorials at various levels.  I found it pretty useful to get my head around some of the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, another great resource is [www.learnvisualstudio.net](http://www.learnvisualstudio.net)

Its not free but it has a plethora of videos covering all aspects of asp.net from 1.1 to 3.5, AJAX, Webservices.

Programmer to Programmer style videos with great examples and downloadable source code.

Good luck :)